# Conseguir los valores de monto total

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT   Ve.ID_Venta, 
        SUM(Costo) Monto_Sin_Descuento, 
        SUM(Costo) * (1-(SUM(Descuento)/COUNT(Descuento)/100)) Monto_Con_Descuento

FROM     LibroVersion V, Detalle_Ventas D, Ventas Ve 

WHERE    V.ISBN = D.ISBN AND D.ID_Venta = Ve.ID_Venta 

GROUP BY Ve.ID_Venta

ORDER BY 1;
```

El Dividir SUM(Descuento) entre COUNT(Descuento) es para poder usar el valor, pero como se repite varias veces quiero ocupar solo uno de esos valores (que son los mismos)
Tengo este código SQL que se supone que me ayudaría a mostrar el monto total de una venta, en donde cada venta tiene su porcentaje de descuento, sin embargo, no consigo que en la última columna me arroje lo que realmente se pagó por todas las consultas de tal forma que pueda evitar que aparezcan valores nulos como en la tercer columna, pero no lo consigo.
La imagen de la base es la siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y aquí están algunas de las tuplas del resultado de mi consulta:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En donde como podemos ver, en el Monto ya con descuento me aparecen ciertos valores nulos en donde no hay descuento (Como en la primer tupla) y en ese caso quiero que me muestre el valor sin el descuento que sería con un descuento de 0%.

Comment: como debe ser esa formula??? dudo que sea restando 3 veces el mismo valor....

Comment: SUM(Costo) - (SUM(Costo) - (SUM(Costo) * (1-(SUM(Descuento)/COUNT(Descuento)/100)))) Monto_Real 

Aquí lo que hago es tratar de evitar valores nulos. 
Primero tengo el Monto total que sería el SUM(Costo) pero lo que quiero es el que ya tiene descontada cierta cantidad (Esa cantidad puede ser 0), entonces le resto al monto total la diferencia entre ese mismo valor y el valor con descuento.
Pero no entiendo por qué sale Null

Comment: para evitar nulos se usa la funcion coalesce... buscala, es sql ansi para todas las bases igual. sigo sin entender que hace esa funcion, o como queres calcular lo que queres calcular...

Comment: Explicando eso vi un problema en mi planteamiento

Comment: para lo que te falta, usa coalesce.. buscalo en google...

Comment: Eso soluciona el problema, muchas gracias